# using retrofit process of retrying going slow

Tags: android, retrofit, android-ion

I am new for retrofit and I am using it and I have implemented in activity directly not inside thread and when I am starting then it taking lot of time and blocking User Interface also and after getting response and when I hit again same by restarting activity It wait unlimited time. It is being stuck on same request.

I have an activity and having three fragment and using pager so firstly I am hitting web-service inside activity and using call back updating my recycler view adapter

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("xyz.co.in/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
app = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<List<Pojo>> listCall = app.getDetails();
sb = new StringBuffer("xyz.co.in/api/api.php?api=user&ver=1.0&key=56F353E05208C8E&cmd=OBJECT_GET_LOCATIONS");
sb.append(",");

listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Pojo>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<List<Pojo>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

        final ArrayList<Pojo> list = (ArrayList<Pojo>) response.body();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                sb.append("" + list.get(i).getImei());
            else
                sb.append(";" + list.get(i).getImei());

        }
        Ion.with(MainActivity.this).load(sb.toString())
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        if (e != null)
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error : " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else {
                            try {
                                list_pojo = new ArrayList<>();
                                address_description = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                    JsonObject jsonObject = result.getAsJsonObject(list.get(i).getImei().toString());
                                    list_pojo.add(new Imei_Pogo(jsonObject.get("dt_server").getAsString(), jsonObject.get("dt_tracker").getAsString(), jsonObject.get("lat").getAsDouble(), jsonObject.get("lng").getAsDouble(), jsonObject.get("altitude").getAsString(), jsonObject.get("angle").getAsString(), jsonObject.get("speed").getAsInt()));
                                    geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation( jsonObject.get("lat").getAsDouble(), jsonObject.get("lng").getAsDouble(), 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
                                    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                                    String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                    String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                                    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                                    String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                                    address_description.add(address + "," + city + "," + state + "," + country + "-" + postalCode);
                                }
                               // new MyDataBase(getApplicationContext()).insertData(list,list_pojo,address_description);
                                callback.updateUI(list, list_pojo,address_description);

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            } catch (Exception g) {
                                g.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            finally {
                                if(dialog.isShowing())
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: You have Ion and Retrofit, why? You only need one of those

Comment: I have no idea how can i again hit after first hit response

Comment: Hit what? You call `enqueue`, and you process that data in `onResponse`... That's it... `Ion.with` is not needed